# Error while installing angular cli process exit with status 128

Tags: git, npm, ssh

```py
C:\Users\Moaz Azam\demoblog>npm install -g angular/cli
```

> npm ERR! Error while executing:
>   npm ERR! D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/angular/cli.git
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Host key verification failed.
>   npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   npm ERR! and the repository exists.
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

Comment: can you try with `@angular/cli` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is to use the latest npm:

npm install -g npm

Then You can use ,

npm i @angular/cli